# How to change a Button action with Segmented Control

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, segment

I have a button which has an action that gives a push to another view. My goal is to make this button to open different views according to the selected segment. For example: I have a button called "Request" and have a control segment with two segments, called "Pizza Salt" and "Sweet Pizza." When selected, for example, "Pizza Salt" in the segment and then immediately click the "Request" button, I want to open a view to the menu of "Salt Pizza.", And selected "Sweet Pizza" I want the button to open another view with the menu of the "Sweet Pizza."

Note: I already have the two controllers ready with views.

What code do I use?

My code:

```
- (IBAction)changeButtonCode:(id)sender {
    if (_firstSegmentSixthView.selectedSegmentIndex == 0);
}

- (IBAction)pushToNextView:(id)sender {


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon pressing the request button:

```
if (_firstSegmentSixthView.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) //salty
{
    ViewController1 *vc1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
else if (_firstSegmentSixthView.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) //sweet
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, but what I want is: when I select the "salty" segment, change the action button that when I click in the button, enter the view of the "salty". I do not want that when I select a segment, switch to the view automatically.

Comment: Thats exactly the answer. You first select a segment and then when pressing the action button you use the code above to push the correct view controller.

Comment: Nooo, u dont understand me. Look: i have a button called "Request" and a control segment called: [Salty]|[Sweet], when i select "Salty", for example, i need to click in the button "Delivery" to push the view, and not push automatically after clicked in the segment.

Comment: Listen very carefully now: THE CODE ABOVE IS FOR YOUR "DELIVERY" BUTTON AND ##NOT FOR YOUR SEGMENT CONTROL!

Comment: wow, I traveled cool in my mind. sorry and thanks for the answer! this is a result of staying all day frying in objective c haha, sorry again, man!

Answer (score 2):

Use this method to perform actions on different buttons of UIsegmentControl:

```
- (IBAction) segmentControlBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl* segmentControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    int index = [segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex];

    switch(index)
    {
        case 0: // Perform action on first button of segment controller 
                break;
        case 1: // Perform action on second button of segment controller 
                break;
        case 2: // Perform action on second button of segment controller 
                break;
        default 
               break;

    }
}
```

Connect this method with `UISegmentControl` from `xib`, using the attribute `"value changed"`.